# Python specify lambda arguments as a function argument

Tags: python, lambda

Is there any possibility to specify how many arguments a lambda as a function argument can take?

For example:

```
def func(k=lambda x:return x**2):
   return k
```

Could i specify, if k is not the standard lambda, that k is supposed to take exactly one argument?

Max

Comment: Why are you taking a lamda as an argument?  Also what you have in your question is not valid python

Comment: Also calling the lambda with not enough args would error  so you could just catch that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this using [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

```
import inspect
def func (k = lambda x: x ** 2):
    if not callable(k) or len(inspect.getargspec(k).args) != 1:
        raise TypeError('k must take exactly one argument.')
    # Do whatever you want
```

Note that the above will miserably fail with something like (while it shouldn't):

```
func (lambda x, y = 8: x + y)
```

...so you will need something a bit more complicated if you want to handle this case:

```
import inspect
def func (k = lambda x: x ** 2):
    if not callable(k):
        raise TypeError('k must be callable.')
    argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(k)
    nargs = len(argspec.args)
    ndeft = 0 if argspec.defaults is None else len(argspec.defaults)
    if nargs != ndeft + 1:
        raise TypeError('k must be callable with one argument.')
    # Do whatever you want
```